# std::future with temporary std::promise

Tags: c++, promise, std, future

I have a problem with understanding how the promise cooperates with future.
I have a function that is returning `std::future` like in this example:

```
std::future<int> calcSomeValue() {
}
```

My problem is that this future can be either calculated asynchronously spawning a thread, or can have a result already ready to return, so I would like to have it returned using `std::promise` without running a thread. But... I don't know if this is safe or not or what else could I do.
See example:

```
std::future<int> calcSomeValue() {
    if (resultIsReady()) {
        std::promise<int> promise; // on the stack
        std::future<int>  rv = promise.get_future(); // is future part of the memory occupied by promise?

        promise.set_value(resultThatIsReady); // does it store the value in promise or in future?
        return rv; // <--- What will happen when promise is lost?
    }
    else {
        return std::async(....)
    }
}
```

See the comment in the code above.
Is future accessing promise variable when `.get()` is called, where promise is already fulfilled? If it is then I will have a big doo doo here.

Can anyone advise me how can I return `std::future` in this particular case?

Comment: Once the promise's value is set, the shared state object shared between the promise and the future is also set. The promise doesn't have to survive after being set. The `std::promise` is the mail slot where you push the response through, it doesn't store the response.

Comment: This design seems odd to me. If you are checking that a result is already ready, it implies an external worker might be calculating the result *right now*. If that's the case, you start another worker to do that calculation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux. Merci! Do you happen to have any reference to doc that says it is safe to abandon promise? Is it possible that this may be depended on implementation?
As per the oddness, we are dealing with a very rare (once a day) calculation (of course it looks differently than this one) and a single threaded, however context switching environment. Since we have to return result (taken from a calculated set of results) as fast as possible, we do not now want to spawn threads each time we request the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `promise`-object is associated with a shared state (note the "shared"). When calling `promise::get_future`, you'll receive a `future`- object associated with the same shared state as the one with which the respective promise object is associated. This state will live at least as long as one associated producer (i.e. the promise) or a consumer (i.e. the future) lives. Hence, it does not matter if the `promise`'s lifetime ends before the corresponding `future`-object.

Not normative, but see, for example, [promise](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/promise/) as described at cplusplus.com:

> The lifetime of the shared state lasts at least until the last object
>   with which it is associated releases it or is destroyed. Therefore it
>   can survive the promise object that obtained it in the first place if
>   associated also to a future.